# WCF DataContract Issue

Tags: wcf, datacontract

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Solution with 3 projects: Shared, which contains a single class called `ServiceResult`.  The class is attributed with `DataContract(IsReference=true)`, and each property is attributed with `DataMember`.  The next project is a WCF service, with a method that returns the `ServiceResult` type.  The third project is a command line app with a Service Reference to the WCF service.  This also has a reference to the Shared project.

No matter what I do, if the `DataContract` attribute is on the `ServiceResult` class, I don't get my proxy client in the console application.  As soon as I replace the `DataContract` attribute with the `Serializable` attribute, and refresh my service reference, I get my proxy client in the command line app.

I'd like to have this class attributed with the `DataContract` attribute, as I want to take advantage of the `IsReference` property to maintain object references.

Has anyone seen anything like this before, and if so, how did you solve it?

Thanks!

I should add that the ServiceResult class is a generic type:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class ServiceReferences<TReturn>{...}
```

Comment: How do you use that contract in your service or operation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, he, I didn't realize that I can't serialize generic types, while at the same time, referencing the the same custom type client side.  The client proxy wanted to use a type called ServiceResultOfInt, but the client code was using ServiceResult<int>.  Problem solved.  Thanks, though!